# Restricting the input of a text Filed in HTML without refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Hey I am Using a Form

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p>Enter Roll Number:
<input type="text" name="roll" maxlength="6" placeholder="123456" size="7"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

For taking input from the User (Roll Number)
I want that on Key Press event the user can only able to type between 0-9 and Delete and Backspace and TAB button only. 
All other Key must be Restricted from Typing.
And one more thing if the field is empty then the form shouldn't be posted.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Does it need to be that restrictive or do you just want to make sure only numbers are submitted?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will use jQuery, as it is probably the simplest syntax to achieve such a thing.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="roll"]').keypress(function(e) {
            // Check out which keys are pressed
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 8: //backspace
                case 9: // TAB
                case 46: // delete
                case 48: // 0
                case 49: // 1
                case 50: // 2
                case 51: // 3
                case 52: // 4
                case 53: // 5
                case 54: // 6
                case 55: // 7
                case 56: // 8
                case 57: // 9
                case 96: // numberpad = 0
                case 97: // numberpad = 1
                case 98: // numberpad = 2
                case 99: // numberpad = 3
                case 100: // numberpad = 4
                case 101: // numberpad = 5
                case 102: // numberpad = 6
                case 103: // numberpad = 7
                case 104: // numberpad = 8
                case 105: // numberpad = 9
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Z6y/)

Comment: What it wud be if i use Numeric Key pad...??

Comment: All the key codes are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent

Comment: @PrasathK 96 = 0, 97 = 1, 98 = 2, 99 = 3, 100 = 4, 101 = 5, 102 = 6, 103 = 7, 104 = 8, 105 = 9

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee Sorry, try keypress instead of keyup, try the new code, I edited.

Comment: hey its still not working .....
i uploaded it here 
http://www.chatat.tk/val.html

Comment: Are you using jquery? Please check the linked jsfiddle for the working example. http://jsfiddle.net/c4Z6y/

Comment: ya urs is working ..... can u say why mine is not working ?
actually i am a beginner

Comment: Do you have a link to your live site?

Comment: You are using HTML4 DOCTYPE, so try and replace <script> to <script type="text/javascript"> do this for both the script tag where you link jquery and the script tag where you execute the code I gave you.

Comment: Are you using the number pad or the keys above the qwerty? I updated the answer to include numberpad keys.

Comment: the query (Laptop)
!@#$%^&*()
1234567890

Comment: does the my sample code in 
www.chatat.tk/val.html
works for you ?

Comment: hi, please try and copy/paste this full paste into your document and see if it works for you. http://pastebin.com/9jQSDd8K

Comment: hey  sorry pastebin is restricted in my network ... its Blocked
can you give me alternate website

Comment: Try and change your DOCTYPE, make the first few lines like this, everything else should be the same:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: hey @francisco.preller did u see i had changed as u stated ... but still not work ... did it work for you ?

Comment: The exact same code works on our server, but not on yours, it is quite strange. I am sorry, without more information I am unsure what else to suggest :(

Answer (score 0):

Here your JS code for key press and form submit

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="roll"]').keypress(function(e) {
            // Check out which keys are pressed
            if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46 || (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
                   return true;
            } else {
                   return false;
            }
        });

    });

    function checkvalid() {
        if($('#roll').val() != '') {
           $('#frmid').submit();
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here HTML code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frmid" name="frmid" onsubmit="checkvalid();">
<p>Enter Roll Number:
<input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" maxlength="6" placeholder="123456" size="7"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn" />
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: hey @kautil its not working ..... I want j query which check the conditions without reloading / submitting the form